# Which event loop phase event emitter callbacks are executed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, event-loop

I have started learning node event loop, based on my understanding, other than `setInterval, setImmediate, setTimeout` callbacks, all will execute in `poll` phase, but when check with event emitter callbacks, its executes on every phase, lets say the below code

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const fs = require('fs');

const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
eventEmitter.on('emit', (eventName) => {
  console.log('<----- an event occurred! --->', eventName);
});

setTimeout(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(' setTimeout 0');
    eventEmitter.emit('emit', 'emit inside setTimeout 0');
  }, 0);

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(' setTimeout 5');
    eventEmitter.emit('emit', 'setInterval inside setTimeout 5');
  }, 5);

  process.nextTick(() => {
    console.log('process.nextTick');
    eventEmitter.emit('emit', 'emit inside process.nextTick');
  });

  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    console.log('Promise.resolve()');
    eventEmitter.emit('emit', 'emit inside Promise.resolve()');
  });

  setImmediate(() => {
    console.log('setImmediate');
    eventEmitter.emit('emit', 'emit inside setImmediate 1');
  });

  fs.readFile(__filename, () => {
    console.log('fs.readFile');
    eventEmitter.emit('emit', 'emit inside fs.readFile');
  });


console.log('sync');
}, 0)
```

If i print the output it looks like below

```
sync
process.nextTick
<----- an event occurred! ---> emit inside process.nextTick
Promise.resolve()
<----- an event occurred! ---> emit inside Promise.resolve()
setImmediate
<----- an event occurred! ---> emit inside setImmediate 1
setTimeout 0
<----- an event occurred! ---> emit inside setTimeout 0
setTimeout 5
<----- an event occurred! ---> setInterval inside setTimeout 5
fs.readFile
<----- an event occurred! ---> emit inside fs.readFile
```

How this event emitter callback is executed as soon as event is emitted on every phase?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question a bit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [node's docs](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#emitteremiteventname-args) about `EventEmitter#emit()`:

> Synchronously calls each of the listeners registered for the event named `eventName`, in the order they were registered, passing the supplied arguments to each.

The callbacks are called **synchronously**, so they're fired from whatever the phase the event-loop was in at the time `emit()` is called. If you're curious about a particular built-in event, you'd have to in the source where that event in particular is fired.